# Multiple clipping areas on Fabric.js canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, photo, fabricjs, image-clipping

For making [Photo Collage Maker](https://editphotosforfree.com), I use fabric js which has an object-based clipping feature. This feature is great but the image inside that clipping region cannot be scaled, moved or rotated. I want a fixed position clipping region and the image can be positioned inside the fixed clipping area as the user want.

I googled and find very near solution.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(10,10,150,150);
ctx.rect(180,10,200,200);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.clip();
```

[Multiple Clipping Areas on fabric js canvas](https://jsfiddle.net/tbqrn/)

where the image of one clipping region has appeared in another clipping region. How can I avoid this or is there another way of accomplishing this using fabric js.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could select my answer, there being no other answers, and assuming of course that it works for you.

Comment: @ep4f This is exactly what i am after, did you solve this using the answer below? - if so how did you stop when you scale the images bigger, the clipping area and position changes? How can i make it so the clipping area is always that size and position?

Comment: If someone have noticed issues with clipping to a group of objects in Fabric.js, then should take a look to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39194409/738017) too.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This can be accomplished with Fabric using the `clipTo` property, but you have to 'reverse' the transformations (scale and rotation), in the `clipTo` function.

When you use the `clipTo` property in Fabric, the scaling and rotation are applied *after* the clipping, which means that the clipping is scaled and rotated with the image. You have to counter this by applying the exact *reverse* of the transformations in the `clipTo` property function.

My solution involves having a `Fabric.Rect` serve as the 'placeholder' for the clip region (this has advantages because you can use Fabric to move the object around and thus the clip region.

Please note that my solution uses the [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/) utility library, particularly for [`_.bind()`](https://lodash.com/docs#bind) (see code for context).

## [Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/natchiketa/gXZJf/)

---

## Breakdown

### 1. Initialize Fabric

First, we want our canvas, of course:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
```

### 2. Clip Region

```js
var clipRect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    left: 180,
    top: 10,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    selectable: false
});
```

We give these `Rect` objects a name property, `clipFor`, so the `clipTo` functions can find the one by which they want to be clipped:

```js
clipRect1.set({
    clipFor: 'pug'
});
canvas.add(clipRect1);
```

There doesn't *have* to be an actual object for the clip region, but it makes it easier to manage, as you're able to move it around using Fabric.

### 3. Clipping Function

We define the function which will be used by the images' `clipTo` properties separately to avoid code duplication:

Since the `angle` property of the Image object is stored in degrees, we'll use this to convert it to radians.

```js
function degToRad(degrees) {
    return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
}
```

`findByClipName()` is a convenience function, which is using [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/), to find the with the `clipFor` property for the Image object to be clipped (for example, in the image below, `name` will be `'pug'`):

```js
function findByClipName(name) {
    return _(canvas.getObjects()).where({
            clipFor: name
        }).first()
}
```

And this is the part that does the work:

```js
var clipByName = function (ctx) {
    var clipRect = findByClipName(this.clipName);
    var scaleXTo1 = (1 / this.scaleX);
    var scaleYTo1 = (1 / this.scaleY);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(degToRad(this.angle * -1));
    ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(
        clipRect.left - this.left,
        clipRect.top - this.top,
        clipRect.width,
        clipRect.height
    );
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

*NOTE*: *See below for an explanation of the use of `this` in the function above.*

### 4. `fabric.Image` object using `clipByName()`

Finally, the image can be instantiated and made to use the `clipByName` function like this:

```js
var pugImg = new Image();
pugImg.onload = function (img) {    
    var pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
        angle: 45,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        left: 230,
        top: 170,
        scaleX: 0.3,
        scaleY: 0.3,
        clipName: 'pug',
        clipTo: function(ctx) { 
            return _.bind(clipByName, pug)(ctx) 
        }
    });
    canvas.add(pug);
};
pugImg.src = 'https://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg';
```

#### What does `_.bind()` do?

Note that the reference is wrapped in the [`_.bind()`](https://lodash.com/docs#bind) function.

I'm using `_.bind()` for the following two reasons:

1. We need to pass a reference `Image` object to `clipByName()`
2. The `clipTo` property is passed the canvas context, not the object.

Basically, `_.bind()` lets you create a version of the function that uses the object you specify as the `this` context.

Sources

1. https://lodash.com/docs#bind
2. https://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#clipTo
3. https://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/

Comment: The fiddle needs updating (as location of fabricjs has changed): http://jsfiddle.net/32Acb/

Comment: @natchiketa This is exactly what i am after apart from one thing - can i ask why the actual images and clipping areas don't match up with the black rectangles? And why when you scale the images bigger, the clipping area and position changes? How can i make it so the clipping area is always that size and position?

Comment: Fabric has a utils class where it have a degreesToRadians function.
    fabric.util.degreesToRadians(value)

Comment: TypeError: _(canvas.getObjects()).where is not a function. (In '_(canvas.getObjects()).where({
               clipFor: name
           })', '_(canvas.getObjects()).where' is undefined)

Answer (score 11):

I have tweaked the solution by @natchiketa as the positioning of the clip region was not positioning correctly and was all wonky upon rotation. But all seems to be good now. Check out this modified fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/PromInc/ZxYCP/

The only real changes were made in the clibByName function of step 3 of the code provided by @natchiketa. This is the updated function:

```
var clipByName = function (ctx) {
    this.setCoords();

    var clipRect = findByClipName(this.clipName);

    var scaleXTo1 = (1 / this.scaleX);
    var scaleYTo1 = (1 / this.scaleY);
    ctx.save();

    var ctxLeft = -( this.width / 2 ) + clipRect.strokeWidth;
    var ctxTop = -( this.height / 2 ) + clipRect.strokeWidth;
    var ctxWidth = clipRect.width - clipRect.strokeWidth + 1;
    var ctxHeight = clipRect.height - clipRect.strokeWidth + 1;

    ctx.translate( ctxLeft, ctxTop );

    ctx.rotate(degToRad(this.angle * -1));
    ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.rect(
        clipRect.left - this.oCoords.tl.x,
        clipRect.top - this.oCoords.tl.y,
        ctxWidth,
        ctxHeight
    );
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Two minor catches I found:

1. Adding a stroke to the clipping object seems to throw things off by a few pixels. I tried to compensate for the positioning, but then upon rotation, it would add 2 pixels to the bottom and right sides. So, I've opted to just remove it completely.
2. Once in a while when you rotate the image, it will end up with a 1px spacing on random sides in the clipping.

Comment: Note - I found that my original fiddle didn't work right in FireFox.  I was able to fix that by using FabricJS 1.4.8 instead of 1.4.0.  It appears there is some bug/conflict with FF and crossOrigin images.
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/903

I've updated the fiddle link in my post above.

Comment: Note that it is required to keep aspect ratio of the image. If you dont it will produce some strange effects. This is probably some issue with the transformation matrix

Comment: In my case clipping area is not adopting angle given to rect. prntscr.com/8gw2qi Clipping area always get the straight. This should fit exactly in this frame section. but its clipping by 90 degree. any thoughts ?

Answer (score 8):

Update to @Promlnc answer.

You need to replace the order of context transformations in order to perform proper clipping.

1. translation
2. scaling
3. rotation

Otherwise, you will get wrongly clipped object - when you scale without keeping aspect ratio (changing only one dimension).

[image: bad]

Code (69-72):

```
ctx.translate( ctxLeft, ctxTop );

ctx.rotate(degToRad(this.angle * -1));
ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
```

Replace to:

```
ctx.translate( ctxLeft, ctxTop );
ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
ctx.rotate(degToRad(this.angle * -1));
```

See this:
https://jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/185/

Proper result:

[image: good]

**UPDATE 1:**

I have developed a feature to clip by polygon:
https://jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/198/

[image: poly]

Comment: In my case clipping area is not adopting angle given to rect.
http://prntscr.com/8gw2qi 
Clipping area always get the straight. This should fit exactly in this frame section. but its clipping by 90 degree.  any thoughts ?

Comment: @deveshsinghal Ask new question. I will answer you. This is not a topic of this question.

Comment: ok @Luk ,  but I got solution of my problem in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505705/clipping-area-angle-not-reflected

Comment: Unfortunately I have already started to code my solution :P Try it, maybe it will help you somehow.

Comment: I have another question for you. ;) :P
please have a look if you can help. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626889/multiple-object-in-a-clipping-section-in-fabric-js-canvas

Answer (score 4):

This can be done much more easily. Fabric provides [render](https://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#render) method to clip by the context of another object.

Checkout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efmbrm4v/2). I saw this on a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27850984/1056566).

```js
obj.clipTo = function(ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

    clippingRect.render(ctx);

    ctx.restore();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

As I tested all fiddles above they have one bug. It is when you will flip X and Y values together, clipping boundaries will be wrong. Also, in order not doing all calculations for placing images into the right position, you need to specify `originX='center'` and `originY='center'` for them.

Here is a clipping function update to original code from @natchiketa

```js
var clipByName = function (ctx) {
    var clipRect = findByClipName(this.clipName);
    var scaleXTo1 = (1 / this.scaleX);
    var scaleYTo1 = (1 / this.scaleY);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(0,0);
        
    //logic for correct scaling
    if (this.getFlipY() && !this.getFlipX()){
        ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, -scaleYTo1);
    } else if (this.getFlipX() && !this.getFlipY()){
        ctx.scale(-scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
    } else if (this.getFlipX() && this.getFlipY()){
        ctx.scale(-scaleXTo1, -scaleYTo1);
    } else {
        ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
    }

    //IMPORTANT!!! do rotation after scaling
    ctx.rotate(degToRad(this.angle * -1));
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(
        clipRect.left - this.left,
        clipRect.top - this.top,
        clipRect.width,
        clipRect.height
    );
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Please check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32Acb/87/)

Comment: This is working fine, I have origin center for an object, Previously I wasn't using origin, Now I am having problem on calculating top and left dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest update on `fabric 1.6.0-rc.1`, you are able to skew the image by hold shift and drag the middle axis.

I have trouble with how to reverse the skew so that the clipping area stays the same. I have tried the following code to try to reverse it back, but didn't work.

```js
var skewXReverse = - this.skewX;
var skewYReverse = - this.skewY;

ctx.translate( ctxLeft, ctxTop );
ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
ctx.transform(1, skewXReverse, skewYReverse, 1, 0, 0);
ctx.rotate(degToRad(this.angle * -1));
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uimos/bntepzLL/5/

Answer (score -1):

Update to previous guys answers.

```
ctx.rect(
    clipRect.oCoords.tl.x - this.oCoords.tl.x - clipRect.strokeWidth,
    clipRect.oCoords.tl.y - this.oCoords.tl.y - clipRect.strokeWidth,
    clipRect.oCoords.tr.x - clipRect.oCoords.tl.x,
    clipRect.oCoords.bl.y - clipRect.oCoords.tl.y
);
```

Now we are able to scale the clipping area without a doubt.

Comment: If you are updating others' answers, update them instead of posting another answer.