# Fabric.js Clip Canvas (or object group) To Polygon

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas drawn in Fabric.js that i am adding a group of rectangles to, i want to limit the edges of those rectangles as a group to not go outside a certain area.

Imagine making a stripy t-shirt, the stripes are make by using a series of rectangles and i need to keep them to the shape of the t-shirt.

I think its better to clip the entire canvas to the shape of the t shirt, so anything i add to it remains within the t-shirt but i am stuck. So far i am only clip to basic circles and rectangles.

Thanks

Comment: can we cllipped by the image shape to image shape ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just render a shape inside `canvas.clipTo` :)

I just loaded a random SVG shape in [kitchensink](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink) and did this:

```
var shape = canvas.item(0);
canvas.remove(shape);
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
  shape.render(ctx);
};
```

[image: canvas clipped to a shape]

As you can see, entire canvas is now clipped by that SVG shape.

Comment: @simmisimmi it's a first item on canvas

Comment: @kangax can u give me example for it or any fiddle.

Comment: can we clipped by the image shape to image shape

Comment: Canvas clipping is working perfect but this clipTo function is also clipping canvas' backgroundimage, I don't want its backgroundImage to be clipped.

Comment: This `clipTo` does not work if there are multiple paths in the SVG. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915711/fabric-js-grouping-svg-elements) question.

Comment: i did the same but i am getting error that shape is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/198/

[image]

```
var clipPoly = new fabric.Polygon([
    { x: 180, y: 10 },
    { x: 300, y: 50 },
    { x: 300, y: 180 },
    { x: 180, y: 220 }
], {
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    left: 180,
    top: 10,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    fill: '#DDD', /* use transparent for no fill */
    strokeWidth: 0,
    selectable: false
});
```

You can simply use Polygon to clip. Answer is based on @natchiketa idea in this question [Multiple clipping areas on Fabric.js canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437696/multiple-clipping-areas-on-fabric-js-canvas)