# Lasso tool in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs, freeform

I'm trying to build a freeform lasso tool to clip an image inside canvas. I'm using [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) to draw the shape.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

img.onload = function() {
  var OwnCanv = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    isDrawingMode: true
  });

  OwnCanv.freeDrawingBrush.color = "purple"
  OwnCanv.freeDrawingBrush.width = 4

  ctx.clip();

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

img.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Jbassette4.jpg?uselang=fi";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

This is my attempt which doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong here ?

Can anyone help me please? It would really be appreciated.

Comment: the question is missing

Comment: Good start, but please try to explain what is going wrong for you - is there an error, does it not work, does it not look right, etc. This will ensure people know where to start in answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

The image needs to be a `fabric.Image`.

You could try something like this:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

img.onload = function() {
    var OwnCanv = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
        isDrawingMode: true
    });

    var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
    });
    OwnCanv.add(imgInstance);

    OwnCanv.freeDrawingBrush.color = "purple"
    OwnCanv.freeDrawingBrush.width = 4

    OwnCanv.on('path:created', function(options) {
        var path = options.path;
        OwnCanv.isDrawingMode = false;
        OwnCanv.remove(imgInstance);
        OwnCanv.remove(path);
        OwnCanv.clipTo = function(ctx) {
            path.render(ctx);
        };
        OwnCanv.add(imgInstance);
    });
}

img.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Jbassette4.jpg?uselang=fi";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

See these resources for more:

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1/

[Multiple clipping areas on Fabric.js canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437696/multiple-clipping-areas-on-fabric-js-canvas)

[Fabric.js Clip Canvas (or object group) To Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816753/fabric-js-clip-canvas-or-object-group-to-polygon)

Comment: This is older but just came across it and it is excellent.   Just curious, do you know if there is a way to take the "cut out" part of the image and save it somewhere as a PNG with transparent background (i.e. the white part of the image after you clip would essentially become transparent around the part that you cut out and want to keep)

Comment: I don't know a way off the top of my head but it's probably possible.