# JavaScript - Free draw an enclosed area on a canvas and record path

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

**CONTEXT**

I want to create an interaction where the user sees an image and can free draw onto the image in order to select a part of it. The goal is to have the user draw an enclosed shape around an area in the image, similar to how the [Photoshop Lasso Tool](http://www.binary-artist.com/photoshop_tutorials/images/lasso_bug.gif) behaves.  I then need to pull the coordinates of everything that falls within the area they have enclosed.

**PROGRESS SO FAR**

On one hand, I know I can use tools such as [sketch.js](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/)  in order to free draw. I have also seen many of drawing various enclosed shapes.

**QUESTION**

1. How can I combine the two concepts above (free draw + enclosed shape) to free draw an enclosed area?
2. How can I record the coordinate that fall within the enclosed area? Or, at the very least, the coordinates of the free drawn path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366490/lasso-tool-in-html5-canvas

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks for your help!