# Lasso tool in html5 canvas - replacing the clipTo function with clipPath

Tags: fabricjs

The code shown below is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366490/lasso-tool-in-html5-canvas). It works fine when using fabric.js/1.4.0, but when I update fabric.js to 2.4.3, it fails to run. The issue is that the clipTo funtion has been replaced by a new function called clipPath. Does anyone know how to update this code so it works with clipPath? I've gone through the docs for clipPath and have been searching Google and Stackoverflow for almost 2 days, but I'm still lost.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

img.onload = function() {
    var OwnCanv = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
        isDrawingMode: true
    });

    var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
    });
    OwnCanv.add(imgInstance);

    OwnCanv.freeDrawingBrush.color = "purple"
    OwnCanv.freeDrawingBrush.width = 4

    OwnCanv.on('path:created', function(options) {
        var path = options.path;
        OwnCanv.isDrawingMode = false;
        OwnCanv.remove(imgInstance);
        OwnCanv.remove(path);
        OwnCanv.clipTo = function(ctx) {
            path.render(ctx);
        };
        OwnCanv.add(imgInstance);
    });
}

img.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Jbassette4.jpg?uselang=fi";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the path, right after being created is already cached.
What you need to do is set the fill to a color that is not null, using the 'set' method.
Then set the path as clipPath for the canvas, or the Object itself.

If you want to set it just for the object, you need to recalculate its correct position.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

img.onload = function() {
    var OwnCanv = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
        isDrawingMode: true
    });

    var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
    });
    OwnCanv.add(imgInstance);
    OwnCanv.controlsAboveOverlay = true;
    OwnCanv.freeDrawingBrush.color = "purple"
    OwnCanv.freeDrawingBrush.width = 4

    OwnCanv.on('path:created', function(options) {
        var path = options.path;
        path.set('fill', 'black');
        console.log(path)
        OwnCanv.isDrawingMode = false;
        OwnCanv.remove(path);
        OwnCanv.clipPath = path;
    });
}

img.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Jbassette4.jpg?uselang=fi";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `objectCaching` on `false` on the path.
Check here:https://jsfiddle.net/jw6rLx5f/2/

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

img.onload = function() {
    var OwnCanv = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
        isDrawingMode: true
    });

    var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
    });
    OwnCanv.add(imgInstance);

    OwnCanv.freeDrawingBrush.color = "purple"
    OwnCanv.freeDrawingBrush.width = 4

    OwnCanv.on('path:created', function(options) {
        var path = options.path;
        path.objectCaching= false;
       
        OwnCanv.isDrawingMode = false;
        OwnCanv.remove(imgInstance);
        OwnCanv.remove(path);
        OwnCanv.clipTo = function(ctx) {
          ctx.save();
            path.render(ctx);
            ctx.restore();
        };
      
        OwnCanv.add(imgInstance);
    });
}

img.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Jbassette4.jpg?uselang=fi";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```