# FabricJS ClipTo Issue for multiple objects like group

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs, cliptobounds

My code is

```
canvas.clipTo = function (ctx) {

    ctx.beginPath();
    for (var i = 0; i < totalPrintArea; i++) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(51,51,51,0)';
        ctx.rect(clipLft[i], clipTp[i], clipW[i], clipH[i], 'rgba(51,51,51,1)', clipRtn[i]);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    canvas.calcOffset();
};
canvas.renderAll();
```

I am taking values from the red dotted box and apply to clip where multiple masks are generating.

My issue is its taking all properties but not rotation for all.

I want to rotate all the rectangles.

I just get some code to change the rotation for the clip like `ctx.rotate(50);` but will not work as I want to make all rotate with their own values

Please guide me for the same.

[image: no description]

Comment: Please check below specific code for the same  

object.clipTo = function (ctx) {
    ctx.rect (x, y, width, height);
}

I want to add rotation property for rectangle and not to the ctx like ctx.rotate(50) not work for me i want like ctx.rect (x, y, width, height, rotate);

Comment: Please guide me for the same

Comment: You could take a look at the answer on this question, there is a method to convert the angle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437696/multiple-clipping-areas-on-fabric-js-canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the original fabricJS github project I saw the comment: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/932#issuecomment-27223912

and decided that I need to prevent making ctx.beginPath all the time:

```
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) { 
var skip = false;
// Workaround to make possible 
// making clipTo with 
// fabric.Group 
var oldBeginPath = ctx.beginPath;
ctx.beginPath = function() {
if (!skip) {
  oldBeginPath.apply(this, arguments);
  skip = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    skip = false;
  }, 0);
}
}
group.render(ctx)
};
```

You can see my workaround to the problem described:
https://jsfiddle.net/freelast/6o0o07p7/

The workaround is not perfect, but hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using the [Andrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38187998/738017), but althouth there some interesting points, it didn't work.

If you try to clip the canvas to a single object (e.g. a circle or a rectangle), you can simply do this:

```
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
    shape.render(ctx); //shape is a circle, for instance
}
```

However, as explained by Kienz and butch2k in the [aforementioned comment on GitHub](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/932#issuecomment-27223912), the problem is that you cannot use this solution with groups. In particular, if you use the following snippet:

```
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
    group.render(ctx);
}
```

you will only see one object of the group to be used for clipping.

The issue is due to the `render` method, which calls the `ctx.beginPath()` and `ctx.closePath()` for each object in the group. And because only the last couple of beginPath-closePath calls will affect the clipping, you need some workaround.

So in my solution, I have temporarily redefined the `ctx.closePath` and `ctx.beginPath` methods (after storing them in other two temporary variables, named `oldBeginPath` and `oldClosePath`) so that they do nothing. Then I call `oldBeginPath` at the beginning, and after rendering all the objects in the group I call the `oldClosePath`.

And now, here is the (working) snippet:

```
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
    var oldBeginPath = ctx.beginPath;
    var oldClosePath = ctx.closePath;

    ctx.beginPath = function() {}
    ctx.closePath = function() {}

    oldBeginPath.apply(ctx);
    group.forEachObject(function(shape){
        shape.render(ctx);
    });
    oldClosePath.apply(ctx);

    ctx.beginPath = oldBeginPath;
    ctx.closePath = oldClosePath;
};
```

Hope this will save someone's spare time in the future.