# Multiple object in a clipping section in fabric Js canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have added a clipping section in my canvas.
   and I am adding multiple object on this. 
The problem is as soon as i add the second object, the first object get invisible.

explained in this

```
var pug = new fabric.Text("Hi ", {
        angle: 0,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        left: 245,
        top: 35,
        scaleX: 0.3,
        scaleY: 0.3,
        clipName: 'pug',
        clipTo: function(ctx) { 
            ctx.save();
              ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
              ctx.rect(
                100, 100,
                200, 200
              );
            clipRect1.render(ctx);
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
            ctx.stroke();
              ctx.restore();
        }
    });
    canvas.add(pug);

    var pug1 = new fabric.Text("Hello", {
        angle: 0,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        left: 300,
        top: 35,
        scaleX: 0.3,
        scaleY: 0.3,
        clipName: 'pug',
        clipTo: function(ctx) { 
            ctx.save();
              ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
              ctx.rect(
                100, 100,
                200, 200
              );
            clipRect1.render(ctx);
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
            ctx.stroke();
              ctx.restore();
        }
    });
    canvas.add(pug1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/202/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change clipping area background to transparent (line 17).
When FabricJS renders second object it overlaps first one.

Comment: Yeah, thats worked. but is there any way to fill color in the clipping section?

Comment: Try to add rectangle filled with desired background on bottom.
Set options "selectable" and "evented" to false in order to prevent selecting it by user.

Comment: I keep fill = transparent and backgroundColor "#DDD" , that didnt worked

Comment: No you didn't understand me. You should create additonal object fabric.Rect with desired background and clip it by you clipping area.

Comment: I still didnt get you, can you update your changes in my fiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89918/discussion-between-devesh-singhal-and-luk).